# Handlebars loop in loop not working

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following handlebars file:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        {{#name_days}}
        <tr>
            <td class="name-days-country">
                <span class="flag-sm flag-sm-{{flag}}"></span>
                <span class="name-days-country-name">{{country}}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="name-day-dates">
                {{#each months}}
                    <td class="name-days-tile">
                        <span>{{this}}</span>
                    </td>
                {{/each}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/name_days}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm expecting `<td class="name-days-tile">` to be inside `<td class="name-day-dates">` but it renders as:

```
<td class="name-day-dates"></div>
<td class="name-days-tile"></div>
```

Why isn't it rendering as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that one cannot put a `td` inside a `td`.

While one can manually do it, without it being valid in plain HTML, handlebars detected the issue and automatically applied a closing `</td>` before adding another opening `<td>` during the render process.